# Adding a new record that has a foreign key relationship using new_foo_path(@bar)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys

I'm trying to add a new `location` to a `restaurant` using Ruby on Rails.

In the `restaurants#show` action I run:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Location', new_location_path(@restaurant) %>
```

And I get a URL: `http://localhost:3000/locations/new.1`, where `1` is the id of the restaurant. But the new location form doesn't appear.

What is the rails way to handle this simple case? Is using `new_FOO_path` even the right thing to be doing?

In this case, I **shouldn't** have a drop down to select the restaurant because I want the end user to only be able to add a `location` to their own restaurant. I would somehow need to have a hidden input with the restaurant ID in the add location form, and also validate the id on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in your routes.rb. Example:

```
resources :restaurants do
  resources :locations
end
```

Then your link target would be `new_restaurant_location_path(@restaurant)`. In your controller, you can find the restaurant via `Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])`.

Alternatively, set the restaurant id as a GET parameter with `new_location_path(:restaurant_id => @restaurant.id)`.

Comment: I can't seem to find the restaurant_id as a hidden field. How can I access it in the view to set the correct `restaurant_id` in the POST action method?

Comment: You don't need to. With a nested route, the restaurant_id is part of the path. Example: `/restaurants/1/locations/new`. Make sure that your location is build correctly in your controller, e.g. `@location = @restaurant.location.build`, then the form should use the correct route. Or use `form_for [@restaurant, @location]`.